# GDB - How does it know about function calling stack?

Tags: assembly, gdb, stack-trace, backtrace

When use gdb to debug assembly program, `bt` will print the calling stack.

**The questions are:**

- *(a)* Does gdb know about that according to `rbp` values stored in register for current function, and in stack for previous rbp values?
- If yes, *(b-1)* how gdb know which function it is according to a `rbp` value? *(b-2)* Is the mapping between stack base & function stored in executable file when `-g` option is specified on compiling? *(b-3)* And how to read that mapping data, with `readelf`? Which part?
- If no, *(c)* then how gdb track the function calling stack?

Comment: `rbp` values are stack address, and don't have a 1:1 mapping with function code addresses/names.  You have to look at return addresses for that.  Ross's answer explains how to find return addresses on the stack while backtracing.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's the `rip` values that help to track function calling stacks with the help of `rbp` I guess. Yes Ross's answer is great, I think `unwind` info is actually used when the executable don't follow the rbp/rsp convention.

Comment: Yes, it is the saved return addresses (`RIP` values) that a backtrace needs to find.  You're right that in the old-style `push rbp` stack-frame-making convention where the saved `rbp` values form a linked list, the return addresses are at a known position within each frame.  (It's not just a metaphor, BTW; it literally is a linked list.  The `RIP` values are just data in each node, not a linked list of their own.  Only the `rbp` values point to the next node.)  Also, I should have said `EIP`/`EBP` value, because I think the `.eh_frame` data is used by default for 64bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Debuggers like GDB have two primary means of walking the stack in order to print a backtrace. They either assume the value in the frame pointer register (RBP) is a pointer to start of a linked list of stack frames, or they use special unwind info stored in the executable that describes how to walk (unwind) the stack.

#### Using the frame pointer

When using the frame pointer, the assumption is that it points to where the current function saved the value of its caller's frame pointer. It also assumes that just before that saved frame pointer is where the return address for the current function is stored. So that's how it knows both what the RBP value of the calling function was, and what function called the current function, which it can easily determine from the return address. It can then find all the previous stack frames and functions on the stack by walking the linked RBP values.

However, this assumes that functions use the frame pointer this way, and generally there's no guarantee that they will.  Basically it's assuming that the function prologue and epilogue looks something like this:

```
func:
    push %rbp         # save previous frame pointer
    mov  %rsp, %rbp   # new frame pointer points to previous value
    sub  $24, %rsp    # allocate stack space for this funciton

    ...

    pop %rbp          # restore previous frame pointer
    ret
```

But when optimizing many compilers won't do this, because they rarely need to use a frame pointer and instead will treat RBP like any other general purpose register and use it for something else.

#### Using unwind info

So to generate a backtrace across functions that don't use RBP as a frame pointer, a debugger can potentially use unwind information. This is special data stored in executables (and dynamic libraries) that describes exactly how to virtually undo all the stack operations performed by a function at any point in the execution of that function. The format and location of the unwind info varies based on the executable format and CPU type.  For ELF x86-64 executables the unwind info is stored in the `.eh_frame` section in a format based on the [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging format's unwind info. This format is too complex to describe here, but you can read the [System V AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Which was the real historical cause and which was the effect?  I thought that unwind metadata was created to allow this optimization in programs that need to unwind their own stack at run-time (e.g. to support exceptions).  Enabling useful backtraces in optimized code that doesn't need exceptions is a bonus.

Comment: Nice metaphor to describe rbp values on stack as linked list, I knew its mechanism, but never though it that way before. `rip` values on stack is stored just above each `rbp` right? it's also like a linked list, thus able to know which function that rip belong to. And, when I removed the `push rbp` instructions, gdb still could provide function calling stack, I guess it's using the `unwind` info. Great answer!

Comment: @EricWang Yes, the RIP value of the caller is stored in the next higher stack slot just before RBP when the compiler creates a "normal" frame pointer based stack frame.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm really not sure what came first. DWARF unwind info was introduced in the DWARF 2 spec in 1993, giving the rational: "Debuggers often need to be able to view and modify the state of any subroutine activation that is on the call stack." There was no mention of using it for exception unwinding. The Design and Evolution of C++, published in 1994, says that "in theory at least" C++ exceptions can be without runtime cost until an exception is thrown, which implies that no C++ implementation at the time used unwind info.

Comment: @PeterCordes On the other hand when PECOFF was introduced with Windows NT in 1993 it supported both FPO (frame pointer omission) records for i386 targets and (crude by comparison to DWARF) unwind info for RISC (MIPS, Alpha) targets. The former was for debuggers only, while the later was primarily for SEH exceptions.